# React state not updating - only updated after first clicked

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Navigation() {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("about");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pageTitle);
  }, [pageTitle]);

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="flex justify-center mt-36">
        <ul className="flex gap-4">
          <NavLink to={"/"}>
            <span className="group transition duration-300">
              about
              <span className="block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-500 h-0.5 bg-sky-600"></span>
            </span>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to={"/portfolio"}
            onClick={() => {
              setPageTitle("portfolio");
            }}
          >
            <span className="group transition duration-300">
              portfolio
              <span className="block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-500 h-0.5 bg-sky-600"></span>
            </span>
          </NavLink>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
          <span className="flex-shrink mx-4 text-gray-400">{pageTitle}</span>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click portfolio, state is not changing. Actually state changes after the first click. I heard that states are asynchronous and have to use useEffect. anyway, I didn't get the point. Where I'm doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used props for this problem and fixed it.

example: <Navigation title={"blog"} />

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put `onClick` on the `<span>` tag

```
          <NavLink
            to={"/portfolio"}
          >
            <span onClick={() => setPageTitle("portfolio")} className="group transition duration-300">
              portfolio
              <span className="block max-w-0 group-hover:max-w-full transition-all duration-500 h-0.5 bg-sky-600"></span>
            </span>
          </NavLink>
```

Comment: I did but still the same thing.

Comment: Maybe add an intermediary function handleClick() for the onClick event to update the state inside the function handleClick()

Comment: function handleClick(title) {
    setPageTitle(title);
  }
onClick={() => handleClick("portfolio")}

I tried this way but still the same.

Comment: Hmmmmm, can you maybe add a snippet, or a sandbox of your code to test it pls?

Answer (score 0):

this will update after first click because you are updating state inside onClick event, btw when do you want your state to be updated? and your useEffect is of no use here it is just consoling your pageTitle value.

Comment: No update on the first click. I see the new pageTitle value on the screen on the second click. Do I need to do function inside of useEffect ?